# Using Jsmooth for creating .exe file

Tags: java, jsmooth

I want to create a .exe file of my application. I read many posts in here and I found out the JSmooth is good choice. I am using Windows. I started with reading JSmooth "read me" file. In step 3.4 it says :

> 3.4 FLTK library

```
 FLTK, available at http://www.fltk.org The easiest way is probably to
 grab a recent source package of fltk, then to run under an MSYS/MINGW
 environment the three commands: "./configure", "make", and "make
 install".
```

I downloaded MinGW but I don't know how to run FLTK under MinGw! Does anyone know?

Comment: *"I read many posts in here and I found out the JSmooth is good choice."*  For a Java based desktop app., [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is a better option for deployment.  (For 'Windows only' development, .Net is arguably a better choice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it strange that you need to compile FLTK library via MinGW just to use JSmooth. If so, run Start Menu => Programs => Mingw => MinGW Shell and change the current path to the root folder where you save FLTK source codes using "CD" DOS command and later type: `"./configure", "make", and "make install"` one by one. Actually you are building FLTK library using GCC compiler supplied by MinGW. Hence, there is a risk if you don't know how to proceed later if there is something wrong in the ./configure script which is in the root folder. http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

As an alternative to JSmooth which is a Java EXE launcher, I suggest you to use the simpler `Launch4J` instead. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Someone may suggest you to use `Java Web Start(JWS)` as well (if you prefer an OS platform-independent Java launcher; please don't if you use Windows native parts in your codes via JNI or JNA since these won't work in Linux, unless you use Wine but still there are more to that....now it sounds too technical, I guess)